# How to stop app from accessing the internet when a blacklisted app is installed

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an app which automatically fetch data online whenever it is opened. I would like to make it a way that the app will only check for update online when a blacklisted app is not detected.

**This is the update core.**

```
    public class UpdateCore extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private static final String TAG = "NetGuard.Download";
    
        private Context context;
    
        private Listener listener;
        private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    
        private HttpURLConnection uRLConnection;
    
        private InputStream is;
        private TorrentDetection torrent;
    
        private BufferedReader buffer;
    
        private String url;
    
         
        public interface Listener {
            
    
            void onLoading();
           
            void onCompleted(String config) throws Exception;
    
            void onCancelled();
    
            void onException(String ex);
        }
    
        public UpdateCore(Context context, String url, Listener listener) {
    
            this.context = context;
            this.url = url;
            this.listener = listener;
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
    
            listener.onLoading();
    
        }
    
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                String api = url;
                if(!api.startsWith("http")){
                    api = new StringBuilder().append("http://").append(url).toString();
                }
                URL oracle = new URL(api);
                HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(oracle.toURI());
                HttpResponse response = Client.execute(httpget);
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                               in, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    
                //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    str.append(line);
                }
                in.close();
                return str.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "error";
            } finally {
                if (buffer != null) {
                    try {
                        buffer.close();
                    } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    }
                }
                if (is != null) {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    
                    }
                }
                if (uRLConnection != null) {
                    uRLConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
           // Log.i(TAG, "Cancelled");
           // pd.dismiss();
            listener.onCancelled();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // wakeLock.release();
            //nm.cancel(1);
           // pd.dismiss();
            try
            {
                if (result.equals("error"))
                {
                    listener.onException(result);
                }
                else {
                    listener.onCompleted(result);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                listener.onException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    
    }
```

**This is the detection code**

```
    public class TorrentDetection
    {
        private Context context;
        private String[] items;
        private TorrentDetection.TorrentListener listener;
        private Timer timer;
        private Handler handler;
        public interface TorrentListener {
            public void detected(ArrayList pkg);
        }
        public TorrentDetection(Context c, String[] i, TorrentListener listener) {
            context = c;
            items = i;
            this.listener = listener;
        }
        private boolean check(String uri)
        {
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            boolean app_installed = false;
            try
            {
                pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
                app_installed = true;
            }
            catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
            {
                app_installed = false;
            }
            return app_installed;
        }
    
        void check() {
            ArrayList arrayList2 = new ArrayList();
            for (String pack : items)
            {
                if(check(pack)){
                    arrayList2.add(pack);
                }
            }
            if (arrayList2.size() > 0)
            {
                
                listener.detected(arrayList2);
                stop();
            }
        }
    
        public void start() {
            handler = new Handler();
            timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                check();
                            }
                        });
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 3000);
        }
    
        public void stop() {
            if(timer != null){
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }
            if(handler != null){
                handler = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The torrent detection code checks if the following apps are installed and returns a message that an unsupported app is installed.

```
    public class Constraints
    {
        public static String updater = "https://pastenord.org/raw/random";
     
        public static String[] torrentList = new String[]{
        
          "com.guoshi.httpcanary",
          
          "com.adguard.android.contentblocker"};
    
    
    }
```

In my MainActivity this initiates the detection before the online update is done with torrent.start();

```
    void update() {
            torrent.start();
            new UpdateCore(this, Constraints.updater, new UpdateCore.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoading() {
    
    
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(final String config) {
                        try {
                            final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(MilitaryGradeEncrypt.decryptBase64StringToString(config, Constraints.confpass));
                            if (Double.valueOf(obj.getString("Version")) <= Double.valueOf(conts.getConfigVersion())) {
    
                            } else {
                                new SweetAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.CUSTOM_IMAGE_TYPE)
                                    .setTitleText("Update")
                                    .setContentText("\n" + obj.getString("Message"))
                                    .setConfirmText("Yes,Update it!")
                                    .setCustomImage(R.drawable.ic_update)
                                    .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                                            sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                                            welcomeNotif();
                                            restart_app();
                                            
                                            try {
                                                db.updateData("1", config);
                                                sp.edit().putString("CurrentConfigVersion", obj.getString("Version")).commit();
                                             
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {}
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .show();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage() , 0).show();
                        }
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled() {
    
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onException(String ex) {
    
                    }
                }).execute();
        }
    
    }
```

It then makes a popup when an unsupported app is detected with this.

```
    torrent = new TorrentDetection(this, Constraints.torrentList, new TorrentDetection.TorrentListener() {
    @Override
    public void detected(ArrayList pkg)
    {
        stopService();
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setTitle("unsupported App!")
            .setMessage(String.format("%s", new Object[]{TextUtils.join(", ", (String[]) pkg.toArray(new String[pkg.size()]))}))
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
            //.setAnimation(Animation.SLIDE)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create()
            //.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_info, Icon.Visible)
            .show();
    }
});
```

I would like the make the app only check for online update only when done of the blacklisted apps are installed. Any form of help is welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: is your code not working?? or do you want a different approach???

Comment: @yahya-durrani yes the code works but I want a way to make the app only check for the online update only after it detects that there is no torrent or sniffing app installed.

Answer (score 0):

use this method to check if an application is installed or not

```
public boolean isPackageInstalled(String packageName, PackageManager packageManager) {
    try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

then to check, simply call:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    boolean isInstalled = isPackageInstalled("com.somepackage.name", pm);
// simply put an if statemement
if(!isInstalled){
//do your update here
}
else{
//display you have installed a blacklisted app
}
```

sidenote, if you are targeting android 11 and above, you need to provide the information about the packages you want to find out about in the manifest like this

```
 <queries>
            <!--Add queries here-->
        <package android:name="com.somepackage.name" />
    </queries>
```